# sql doesn't work after adding WHERE clause

Tags: php, sql

I have the following query:

```
 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM research as r LEFT JOIN research_participants as rp ON rp.research_no = r.id LEFT JOIN researcher as rc ON rc.id = rp.researcher_id where r.id = $researchid");
```

This query works just fine, however, I want it to select only researches that have a status = 'done'
so I changed it to the following:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM research WHERE status= 'done' as r LEFT JOIN researcher as rp ON r.researcher_id = rp.id");
```

It doesn't work unfortunatly.
I also tried the following:

```
 $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM research as r LEFT JOIN researcher as rp ON r.researcher_id = rp.id WHERE status= 'done'");
```

but even this doesn't work.

the research table looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYK63.png)

Comment: you are joining the same table by using a different id?

Comment: What kind of error you get?

Comment: As status is on two tables it will be ambiguous - use the table alias `r.status= 'done'`

Comment: instead of `WHERE` put `AND` I mean `AND status = 'done'` it might work.

Comment: Rule of thumb: *Conditions on the Outer table are placed in WHERE, on the Inner table in ON*: `ON r.researcher_id = rp.id AND status= 'done'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the WHERE clause needs to go after the JOIN, as in:

`$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM research AS r LEFT JOIN researcher AS rp ON r.researcher_id = rp.id WHERE r.status= 'done'");`

Answer (score 0):

If you have same column names on the two tables that you use 'where' then it will be ambiguous.

```
print_r($result);
```

To see the out put take not of the error its displaying.